# jquery reading from file while file is being replaced every 2 hours

Tags: jquery

I am reading data from a text file for my website.
This file will be replaced for every 2 hours by a cron job.

What are the erroneous situations of this approach and how to overcome those?

Comment: What answer you are expecting ? you question is not clear ?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is make a copy of the original file. Then read from the copied file. This way you will not have any issues or errors from the file being replaced by a cron.